Find the coordinates of the image of the sample in the large image in the shortest time

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim intMain() As Integer = GetRgbValues(picMain.Image)
        Dim intTemp() As Integer = GetRgbValues(picTemp.Image)
        Dim ArrTemp = SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep(intTemp, picTemp.Image.Width)
        Dim FirstLine As Integer() = ArrTemp(0)
        Dim IndexOfFirstRow As Integer() = GetIndexsBySpecifiedOrder(intMain, FirstLine) '
        'So far it is going well, but the rest needs to be checked
        Dim ArrMain = SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep(intMain, picMain.Image.Width)
        Dim Coordinates_X_Y As New List(Of Rectangle)
        For Each StartFind In IndexOfFirstRow
            Dim i = StartFind Mod picMain.Image.Width
            Dim t = StartFind \ picMain.Image.Width
            Dim isY As Integer = t
            Dim IsX As Integer = i
            Dim thisIsIt As Integer = 0
            For startCheck = 1 To ArrTemp.Length - 1
                t += 1
                Dim gg = ArrMain(t).Skip(i).Take(ArrTemp(startCheck).Length).Select(Function(h) h).ToArray
                If ArraysSimilarity(gg, ArrTemp(startCheck)) Then
                    thisIsIt += 1
                End If
            Next
            If thisIsIt = ArrTemp.Length - 1 Then
                Dim rec As New Rectangle(IsX, isY, picTemp.Image.Width, picTemp.Image.Height)
                Coordinates_X_Y.Add(rec)
            End If
        Next
        For Each Rec In Coordinates_X_Y
            Dim bt As New Bitmap(picMain.Image)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bt)
            g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Red, 3), New Rectangle(Rec.X, Rec.Y, Rec.Width, Rec.Height))
            picMain.Image = bt
            g.Dispose()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Rec.X & "," & Rec.Y)
        Next

    End Sub
    Function ArraysSimilarity(InArray As Integer(), Simiilar As Integer(), Optional tolerance As Integer = 10) As Boolean
        ArraysSimilarity = InArray.SequenceEqual(Simiilar)
    End Function
    Function SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep(InArray As Integer(), ByStep As Integer) As Integer()()
        SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep = InArray.Select(Function(num, index) New With {.num = num, .index = index}) _
             .GroupBy(Function(x) x.index \ ByStep) _
             .Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(x) x.num).ToArray).ToArray
    End Function
    Function GetIndexsBySpecifiedOrder(inArray As Integer(), SpecifiedOrder As Integer()) As Integer()
        GetIndexsBySpecifiedOrder = inArray.Select(Function(value, index) index) _
                    .Where(Function(index) inArray(index) = SpecifiedOrder(0) AndAlso
                                          If(index + SpecifiedOrder.Length <= inArray.Length,
                                             Enumerable.SequenceEqual(inArray.Skip(index).Take(SpecifiedOrder.Length), SpecifiedOrder),
                                             False)) _
                    .ToArray()
    End Function
    Private Function GetRgbValues(inBitmap As Bitmap) As Integer()
        Dim recBitmap As New Rectangle(0, 0, inBitmap.Width, inBitmap.Height)
        Dim DataMain As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = inBitmap.LockBits(recBitmap, Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = DataMain.Scan0
        Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(DataMain.Stride) * recBitmap.Height

        Dim rgbValues(bytes / 4 - 1) As Integer
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length)
        inBitmap.UnlockBits(DataMain)
        Return rgbValues
    End Function

I could not get color values from byte type. To simplify the task of receiving from integer. You receive from the byte. You receive from the byte so that the tolerance amount can be put in (the following function).
Function ArraysSimilarity(InArray As Integer(), Simiilar As Integer(), Optional tolerance As Integer = 10) As Boolean
        ArraysSimilarity = InArray.SequenceEqual(Simiilar)
    End Function

My result, but a little poor performance:

In the New Code: With this code, 4 images were found within 10 seconds in one large image (1366 x 768 pixels). But you still need to check to get the best speed .thank.
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim pictureBoxMain As PictureBox = picMain
    Dim PictureBoxTemp As PictureBox = picTemp
    Dim intMain As String = GetRgbOfString(pictureBoxMain.Image)
    Dim intTemp() As String = GetArrRgbOfString(PictureBoxTemp.Image, PictureBoxTemp.Image.Width)
    Dim firstRowsRgb As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim Coordinates_X_Y As New List(Of Rectangle)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim FirstLine As String = intTemp(0)
    Do
        i = InStr(i + 1, intMain, FirstLine)
        If i = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Dim XY() As Integer = FindOtherRows(i, intMain, pictureBoxMain.Image.Width, intTemp)
            If XY IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim rec As New Rectangle(XY(0), XY(1), PictureBoxTemp.Image.Width, PictureBoxTemp.Image.Height)
                Coordinates_X_Y.Add(rec)
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    For Each Rec In Coordinates_X_Y
        Dim bt As New Bitmap(pictureBoxMain.Image)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bt)
        g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Red, 3), New Rectangle(Rec.X, Rec.Y, Rec.Width, Rec.Height))
        pictureBoxMain.Image = bt
        g.Dispose()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Rec.X & "," & Rec.Y)
    Next
End Sub
Function FindOtherRows(start As Integer, InMain As String, WidthMain As Integer, RowsFind As String()) As Integer()
    'The trust finding part here is where I failed to identify more than 2 lines.
    ' The tolerance of this part is important. Thank you for checking this part
    Dim thisIsIt As Integer = 0
    Dim GetSeparator As Integer = InMain.Take(start).Count(Function(c) c = "|")
    For Row = 1 To RowsFind.Length - 1
        Dim Result3 As String = String.Join("|", InMain.Split("|").Skip(GetSeparator + WidthMain).Take(Split(RowsFind(Row), "|").Length))
        Dim stt6 As String = Result3 & vbNewLine & RowsFind(Row)
        If Result3 = RowsFind(Row) Then thisIsIt += 1 ' this part Need tolerance 
    Next
    If thisIsIt > 0 Then
        Return {(GetSeparator Mod WidthMain), (GetSeparator \ WidthMain)}
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
Private Function GetRgbOfString(inBitmap As Bitmap) As String
    Dim recBitmap As New Rectangle(0, 0, inBitmap.Width, inBitmap.Height)
    Dim DataMain As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = inBitmap.LockBits(recBitmap, Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = DataMain.Scan0
    Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(DataMain.Stride) * recBitmap.Height
    Dim rgbValues(bytes / 4 - 1) As Integer
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length)
    inBitmap.UnlockBits(DataMain)
    '  Dim Resul As String = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(rgbValues)
    GetRgbOfString = String.Join("|", rgbValues)
End Function
Private Function GetArrRgbOfString(inBitmap As Bitmap, SplitBy As Integer) As String()
    Dim recBitmap As New Rectangle(0, 0, inBitmap.Width, inBitmap.Height)
    Dim DataMain As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = inBitmap.LockBits(recBitmap, Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = DataMain.Scan0
    Dim bytes As Integer = Math.Abs(DataMain.Stride) * recBitmap.Height
    Dim rgbValues(bytes / 4 - 1) As Integer
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, rgbValues.Length)
    inBitmap.UnlockBits(DataMain)
    Return SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep(rgbValues, SplitBy)
End Function
Function SplitArrayBySpecifiedStep(InArray As Integer(), ByStep As Integer) As String()
    Dim Result = InArray.Select(Function(s, i) New With {s, i}).GroupBy(Function(x) x.i \ ByStep).Select(Function(g) String.Join("|", g.Select(Function(x) x.s))).ToArray
    Return Result
End Function


Are you asking for help to include the tolerance in the ArraysSimilarity function?

Both in terms of tolerance and speed. It is weak for large images like the screen of the entire desktop. It cannot be used.
It works for small images

For a speed improvement, as long as you're using .NET Core 2.1 or later, Span might give a useful speed improvement instead of Skip(i).Take(....
